# Using Euler's Totient Function, how do I find all values n such that $\phi(n)=12$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, totient-function

How do I generalize the equation to be able to plug in any result for $\phi(n)=12$ and find any possible integer that works?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! It would be useful to provide some more context for your problem (for example, the definition of $\mu$, which I simply assume denotes the Mobius function here). We have guidelines for asking good questions (which usually mean good answers!) in the [faq](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq), which I suggest you take a look at.

Comment: I am guessing when you write $\mu$ you mean something other then the Mobius function?  Perhaps you are asking for which $n$, $\phi(n)=12$ (the totient function)  It we be good to clarify, since $\mu(n)$ can only take the values $-1,0,1$. (ie, not $12$)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing $\mu$ to $\phi$ since it seems that's what's intended.

Answer (score 20):

Assuming you mean to solve $\phi(n)=12$, you can use the formula for $\phi(n)$ that consists of factoring $n$ and then replacing one copy of every prime $p$ that occurs by $p-1$. You need such $p-1$ to divide $12$, so the only $p$ that can occur are $2,3,5,7,13$, and since occurrence with multiplicity at least $2$ also gives a factor $p$, this cannot happen for $5,7,13$. Also you need a factor $3$, which means you need one of $3,7,13$. Now it is not hard to write down the complete list of (factored) values for $n$: $13,2\times 13,2^2\times7,3\times 7,2\times3\times7,2^2\times3^2$.

Answer (score 10):

Note that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \varphi(n) = \infty$, so for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, the equation $\varphi(n) = k$ has at most finitely many solutions.  How to find all of them?

Solutions to $\varphi(n) = k$ for very small values of $k$ can easily be worked out by hand and probably should be as a good exercise.  For instance if $\varphi(k) \leq 4$ then $n$ can only be divisible by primes $2$, $3$ and $5$, i.e., $n = 2^a 3^b 5^c$ for natural numbers $a,b,c$.  Since $\varphi(5^2) = 5(5-1) = 20$, we must have $c \in \{0,1\}$.  Since $\varphi(3^2) = 3(3-1) = 6$, we must have $b \in \{0,1\}$.  Since $\varphi(2^4) = 2^3(2-1) = 8$, we must have $a \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, which leaves us with $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 = 16$ values of $n$ to check.

The above method will work for any value of $k$, but it gets very slow as $k$ grows.  You could still do it for $k = 12$ -- the value you asked about -- but I wouldn't want to do it by hand even for $k = 50$, say.

In fact for even moderately large $k$ this a problem to get your computer to solve.  However, you should and can do something faster than the method sketched out above.  Better is to use one of the known **explicit lower bounds** for $\varphi$.  In fact this problem came up in a research project for graduate students that I led at UGA a few years back, and the following simple lower bound was perfectly adequate for our purposes:

(1) $\varphi(n) \geq \sqrt{n}$, for $n > 6$

(I learned this originally from wikipedia, although its article on the totient function seems no longer to include this result.)

Thus, assuming $k > 4$ (we did the other case above!) so $n > 6$, using this inequality to find all values of $\varphi(n) = k$ you just need to evaluate the $\varphi$ function at all positive integers in the range $[1,k^2]$: no problem for a computer.

What if you are working with really large $k$?  Well, there is in fact a much better inequality

(2) $\varphi(n) > \frac {n} {e^\gamma\; \log \log n + \frac {3} {\log \log n}}$, for $n > 2$.

This is extremely close to being sharp: if we omitted the $\frac{3}{\log \log n}$ term in the denominator, the right hand side would get ever so slightly larger, but this is large enough for the inequality to be false for infinitely many $n$.  I have not given the matter any deep thought, but if anyone knows a faster way to enumerate the solution set to $\varphi(n) = k$ for large $k$ than by a brute-force search using (2) above, I would be interested to know.

Comment: I'm not convinced that brute-force search using (2) is any faster than (a computerized form of) the algorithm you give in the first few paragraphs.

Answer (score 3):

If there are more than 12 primes between n and n!, then $\phi(n!)>12$ and there is no $m>n!$ such that $\phi(m)>12$.

$n<120$ and a brute force search can be used.

Comment: I think you mean $\phi(m)=12$, not $\phi(m)\gt12$. But I think you need some argument to show that, under the hypotheses, there is no $m\gt n!$ such that $\phi(m)=12$. It is, I think, possible to have $m\gt n!$ with $\phi(m)\lt\phi(n!)$. Take $m$ to be the lcm of the numbers up to $k$, where $k$ is chosen as small as possible, subject to $m\gt n!$.