# Compute $\phi^{-1}(k)$, $\phi$ Euler's totient function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Given a positive integer $k$, I'd like to be able to compute the set of positive integers $m$ such that $m$ is prime to precisely $k$ positive integers less than $m$. In other words, I'd like to compute the set $\phi^{-1}(k)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

We could compute this by brute force using one of the lower bounds for $\phi$ to find an $N$ so that $n \geq N$ implies $\phi(n) > k$ and then we could test all $m < N$ to see if $\phi(m)=k$, but is there are smarter way to compute $\phi^{-1}(k)$?

Comment: Have you considered [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101566/using-eulers-totient-function-how-do-i-find-all-values-n-such-that-phin-12?rq=1)?

Comment: Thanks. I missed that question, where Pete Clark says he doesn't see a smarter way of doing it than using a lower bound. So I think that my question still stands.

Comment: OK. It's more or less a duplicate. The answer seems to be, you can do it, but not without sweat. How do I close the question?