# Solving $\phi(n)=22$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Find all positive integers n such that $\phi(n) = 22$ and prove that
there are no others. Here $\phi$ denotes the Euler $\phi$-function.

Comment: I think the fact that if $n=\prod p_{i}^{a_{i}}$, then $\phi(n) = \prod p_{i}^{a_{i}-1}\cdot (p_{i}-1)$ will help.

Comment: Given the two posted hints, there are two $23$ and $46$.

Comment: I need a rigorous proof that 23 is the only solution.

Comment: Similar questions (with different numbers): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101566/using-eulers-totient-function-how-do-i-find-all-values-n-such-that-phin-12 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127998/find-all-positive-integers-n-such-that-phin-6

Answer (score 9):

**Hint**: Suppose that $\varphi(n) = 22$. Then if we factor $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ then

$$22 = p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_k^{\alpha_k} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_1}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_k}\right) = (p_1^{\alpha_1} - p_1^{\alpha_1 - 1}) \cdots (p_k^{\alpha_k} - p_k^{\alpha_k - 1})$$

Now use the fact that the only divisors of $22$ are $1, 2, 11, 22$.

Comment: I need a rigorous proof that 23 is the only solution

Comment: @leo Which is why I've marked my answer as a hint - it's not too hard given that there's only a few ways to factor $22$; consider the problem for a while.

Comment: @leo 23 is NOT the only solution.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that $n$ cannot be a power of $2$, since in that case $\phi(n)$ would also be a power of two.

This means that $n$ is divisible by an odd prime.

If $p$ and $q$ are two distinct odd primes dividing $n$, then $\phi(n)$ is divisible by $(p-1)(q-1)$ which is a multiple of $4$. But this is not possible.

Thus $n$ is divisible by exactly 1 odd prime. Then, it must have the form

$$n=2^ap^b \, 0 \leq a, 1 \leq b \,.$$

Now, $p-1 |\phi(n)=22$ thus $p-1 \in \{1,2,11, 22 \}$. As $p-1$ is even, the only possibilities are $p-1=2$ or $p-1=22$.

This reduces the problem to two cases.

If $p=3$ then $n=2^a3^b$ with $b >0$ and $a \geq 0$. It is easy to argue there is no solution here.

If $p=23$ then $n=2^a23^b$ with $b >0$ and $a \geq 0$. Then, you need to argue that $b=1$, in which case $n=2^a23$. Then

$$22 =\phi(2^a)\phi(23)=22 \phi(2^a) \Rightarrow \phi(2^a)=1$$

This has two solutions $a=0$ and $a=1$, which yield $n=23$ and $n=46$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hints**: Note that $23$ is prime and $\phi(p)=p-1$ for all primes $p$, since all positive integers less than $p$ are relatively prime to $p$. Thus, $n=23$ is a solution. To find out if there are other solutions, consider [Formula for Euler's Totient Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Since you haven't elaborated on your solution, I'll leave it there for now.

Comment: can you please help me show how to use this formula to show that 23 is the only solution. thanks!

Comment: @leo I hesitate because you haven't shown any work. As per the rules of StackExchange, you should show us that you have made an attempt before we can help you. Sorry.

Comment: @leo I'll give you another hint just because I feel like I'm being mean. Try factorizing $22$ and match it up with the formula.

Comment: okay so. I do that and now i am trying to reason that p*(p-1)=2*11. I know I somehow have to show that (p-1)/2 = 11 where p=23, but i need a clean proof. terribly sorry for bothering you but i have trouble with coming up with clean proofs and my exam is right around the corner. thanks.

Comment: @leo It's fine, I understand. At least we can see now that you're trying. So hint: there are only 4 divisors.

Comment: this thing really isnt working out for me .

Comment: @leo $22$ must be the product of $ 1 - \dfrac {1}{p_i} $s times $n$. Right? Now write that equal $ 2 \cdot 11 $.

Comment: 23 is NOT the only solution.

Comment: Wow, @N.S. is right. There are two positive solutions, namely $n=23$ and $n=46$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there are two solutions, namely $23$ and $46$. Also, there is a more general result, namely:
If $p$ is a prime number with $p>3$ and $2p+1$ is prime, then there are exactly two numbers $n$ such that $\phi (n) = 2p$, namely $2p+1$ and $4p+2$.
Also, there is the Carmichael conjecture (still open, as far as I know) which says that there is no number in the image of phi having a unique antecedent.
In my article "Some remarks on Euler's totient function", I discuss these questions and others.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$. Done for you this time. +1 for a good answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

consider that $\phi(n)=\Pi_1^j p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)$,

that is, for any $p^k$ in prime factorization of $n$, it follows $p^k\mid n\ \Rightarrow p^{k-1}\mid\phi(n)$ and $(p-1)\mid\phi(n)$

with $(p-1)\mid 22$, given possible primes $p=2, 3, 23$, ($11\mid 22$ but $12$ is not prime)

so n is in the form of $n=2^a3^b23^c$

from above know that $p^{k-1}\mid\phi(n)$, then

$2^{a-1}\mid 22,\ a=0,1,2$,

$3^{b-1}\mid 22,\ b=0,1$,

$23^{c-1}\mid 22,\ c=0,1$,

at $c=0$, $\phi(23^0)=1$, $\phi(n)=\phi(2^a)\phi(3^b)\cdot 1$ since $\phi(n)$ in multiplicative and $gcd(2^a,3^b)=1$ for any a and b. within given possible a and b values, there is no combination that can provide 22. ($\phi(2^a)=1,2,\ \phi(3^b)=1,2$)

at $c=1,\ \phi(23)=22,\ \phi(n)=\phi(2^a)\phi(3^b)\cdot22$, then $a=0,1,\ b=0$

hence there are two solutions, $n=2^0\cdot3^0\cdot23^1=23$, and $n=2^1\cdot3^0\cdot23^1=46$