# A base in which all primes end with $5$ different symbols?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

In base $10$, all prime numbers (a part $2$ and $5$) end with $1,3,7$ or $9$, i.e. with four different symbols.

Is there a base in which all prime numbers end with $5$ different symbols (or also with $5$ distinct *groups* of symbols)? If yes, which base?

Thanks for your help! I apologize for such a trivial question!

NOTE: This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2960426/559615).

Comment: Is $5=\phi(n)$ for some $n$?

Comment: Comments in the linked question advised you to study Euler's totient function $\phi(n).\,$ Did you do so before posting this question? If so, where are you stuck?  If not, then you should do so.

Comment: Yes, but I did not understand much. I understood, as @LordSharktheUnknown said, that this is related to the totient function. But I don't know if I can evaluate all its values, since there is not a formula for the primes. Or what am I missing?

Comment: There is no $n$ such that $\phi(n)=5$, as $\phi(n)$ is even for $n>2$.

Comment: @Servaes But sure! Many, many thanks!

Comment: Hmm, when I saw the title (before clicking and reading the question), I was thinking it was: is there any base in which every prime has its 5 last digits distinct?  (To which the answer would be: no, by Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic sequences, in any base there are infinitely many primes ending in 11111.)

Comment: You may be interested in this other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291334/values-taken-by-eulers-phi-function.  However, the answer I gave there is fairly advanced compared to this question.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I see. Sorry, maybe the title was misleading. I am not an expert of this field.

Comment: No, it's just fine, it would indeed be hard to be completely unambiguous in a title, that's why we have the question section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base $b$, all prime numbers that do not divide $b$ end in a number between $0$ and $b$ coprime to $b$. Conversely, for every number between $0$ and $b$ coprime to $b$, there is a prime number ending in $b$. This follows from the [prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions), for example. So the question becomes; for which numbers $b$ are there precisely $5$ numbers between $0$ and $b$ that are coprime to $b$. This number is denoted by $\phi(b)$, where $b$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). It is a simple result that $\phi(b)$ is even for all $b>2$, for example from the identity
$$\phi\left(\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{k_i}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{k_i-1}(p-1),$$
where the $p_i$ are distinct primes and the $k_i$ are positive integers.

---

In fact the only bases $b$ with $\phi(b)<5$ are $b=2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12$. Only in bases $5$ and $8$ do we get precisely $5$ different symbols in which primes can end, where we also count the divisors of the base.

Comment: Thanks again! Also to the other users!

Comment: @AndreaPrunotto There is a simpler proof by reflection (negation) symmetry - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**  $ $ The number of residues coprime to $n> 2$ is *even*: $ $ negation reflection  $\,x\mapsto -x\pmod {\!n}\,$  partitions them into *pairs* (since it has no fixed points: $\,-a\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\, n\mid 2a,\,$ contra $(n,a)=1)$.

**Remark** $\ $ Such use of reflections (or [involutions)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) to pair-up terms frequently proves handy, e.g. see [prior posts here on Wilson's theorem (in groups),](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20%20%20wilson%20involution) esp. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23928/242) to start.

Comment: Thanks for the clever answer! I have to study more!!!!

Comment: Just a little, further question. Is there a way to be sure that, for instance, $\phi(n)=10$ only for $n=10$ and $n=11$?

Comment: @AndreaPrunotto $\phi(10) = 4$ as you mention in your question. You can use the formula for $\phi$ for  things like that (see many prior questions).